# Which tarot card gives the bigger damage boost: The Empress, The Devil or Strength?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

- **The Empress** - Puts you into curse state for a room
- **The Devil** - Acts as a one-time Book of Belial charge
- **Strength** - Gives you a temporary +1 HP and boosts your damage.

All three of these tarot cards are good damage boosting cards, that much I know. However, given two of them, I have no idea which one to keep and which one to leave behind.

Which of the three cards provides the better damage boost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For raw damage, **The Empress** is the best, unless you have Blood of the Martyr, in which case **The Devil** is the best. The specific stats are as follows:

**The Empress** gives you the Whore of Babylon effect for 1 room. Damage is increased by 2.16, and Speed by 0.36.

**The Devil** gives you The Book of Belial effect. Damage is increased by 2. Additionally, if you have the Blood of the Martyr item, your damage is further increased by  1.5x. It also increases the chance of a devil room spawning by 25%.

**Strength** gives you the effect of a Large Odd Mushroom effect for 1 room. HP is increased by 1, Damage is increased by 0.3, Range by 2.75, and Speed is decreased by 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

empress is +3 att

strength is a +3 att and one temp health

devil-max att/near max att

this can be optional depending on what you prefer. 
the devil will maximize your attack so if its a choice between devil and empress then go for devil. Then there is strength, if it is strength vs empress go for strength whereas if it is strength vs devil go with your preference. I prefer devil, but that is only good for a quick victory and if you are better at dodging, but strength is more for slower characters so once again its your choice.

hope this helps you and good luck

I didn't do the exact maths for the attack boosts but that is what it shows for tally counter.